# AI for Web/Contrast/UI components - how to determine "visual boundary" for a product image on a product tile

Tags: accessibility-insights

For example, on the Microsoft website, URL: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/collections/surfacelist?icid=MSCOM_QL_Surface&headerid=department-surface, you see several product tiles that include the image of the product on a pale grey rectangle.

According to Accessibility Insights for Web/Contrast/UI components, any visual boundary that indicates the component's clickable area must have a contrast ratio of at least 3:1 again the adjacent background.

The pale grey rectangle that indicates the clickable boundary only has a 1.14:1 contrast ratio with the background.  So, do these product tiles fail this criterion (WCAG 2.1, 1.4.11 Non-text contrast)?

Answer (score 0):

I am an engineer on the Accessibility Insights team. This is a bug in Accessibility Insights for Web's `Contrast > UI components` requirement, tracked as [microsoft/accessibility-insights-web #2809](https://github.com/microsoft/accessibility-insights-web/issues/2809). The language Accessibility Insights is using for this requirement is more strict than WCAG 2.1 section 1.4.11 requires.

In particular, [Understanding Success Criterion 1.4.11](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/non-text-contrast.html) contains specific language covering this case; its "Boundaries" section clarifies that because these widgets contain text with a 3:1 contrast ratio, and the text indicates the presence of the widget, it is not necessary for the boundary of the widget to have a 3:1 contrast ratio. To quote the guidance (emphasis mine):

> #### Boundaries
>
> This success criteria does not require that controls have a visual boundary indicating the hit area, but if the visual indicator of the control is the **only** way to identify the control, then that indicator must have sufficient contrast. If text (or an icon) within a button or placeholder text inside a text input is visible and there is no visual indication of the hit area then the Success Criterion is passed. **If a button with text also has a colored border, since the border does not provide the only indication there is no contrast requirement beyond the text contrast.**